# dragging- or input movement precision in android compose detectDragGestures' onDrag

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Given this minimal example code fragment:

```
Column {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures(
                        onDragStart = {
                            Log.d("testscreen dragStart", "y = ${it.y.roundToInt()}")
                        },
                        onDrag = {
                            change, dragAmount ->
                            Log.d("testscreen dragging", "y = ${change.position.y.roundToInt()} | \uD835\uDEE5 ${change.positionChange().y.roundToInt()}")
                        }
                )
            }
     )
}
```

I get this debug output:

Slow and fast movement in vertical direction:

[image: Slow Movement]
[image: Fast Movement]

I need pixel-accurate detection of the input to really know where I am on the screen to recognize the hovered elements.

Thus, the question is, why is the detection/output so inaccurate/unreliable and what can I do to achieve my goal(s)?

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows an alternative implementation using the `pointerInteropFilter()` function.

```
val previousY: MutableState<Float?> = remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
Column {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .pointerInteropFilter(
            onTouchEvent = { current ->
                val delta = previousY.value?.run { current.y - previousY.value!! } ?: 0f
                Log.d(
                    "testscreen onTouchEvent",
                    "y = ${current.y.roundToInt()} | \uD835\uDEE5 ${delta.roundToInt()} | ${current.yPrecision.roundToInt()}"
                )
                previousY.value = current.y
                true
            }
        )
    )
}
```

[image: onTouchEvent output]